# Pandas - append to CSV, inconsistent number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am scraping same web pages with BS4, as the data is stored in tables it is pretty simple process. Identify the table and read it using:  `df1 = pd.read_html(str(table))`

Problem is that tables are similar but not always the same, meaning, number of columns is not always the same. 
E.g. Table on page 1 has following columns: `Id, Name, DOB, College, Years_experience, Nationality` , while the same table on page 2 has the same columns expect for College.
So it is:

`Id, Name, DOB, College, Years_experience, Nationality`

vs

`Id, Name, DOB, Years_experience, Nationality`

As I would like to store the data to single CSV, my question is how I can define all the columns, and if table is missing some columns, that it fills null values to CSV.

So something like: check for column names, if not found then fill null values to all rows.

Is there any simple solution for this, or I need to create dict and do everything manually?

Btw; if there is general better solution for this problem it doesn't have to be done with Pandas, just I got used to it as it is super easy to read HTML table

I am doing something like:

So I am doing something like:

```
for urlx in urls:


url = str(urlx)
res = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')



table = soup.find('table', id='abc')

df1 = pd.read_html(str(table))


df1[0]['URL'] = urlx


df1[0].to_csv('_out.csv', encoding='utf=8',float_format="%.3f", index=False, header=None , mode='a')
```

Thanks

edit: added more info

Comment: if you append dataframe, it should match up the like columns, and leave nulls where it's missing that data.

Comment: I can show you exactly, but what's the url? And Pandas is a pretty simple way to pull tables. That's what I always go with for `<table>` tags.

Comment: go edit, and put this is your original post/question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for urlx in urls:
    res = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', id='abc')

    df1 = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    df1['URL'] = urlx

    df = df.append(df1, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

Or possibly skip the whole beautifulsoup and go straight with pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for urlx in urls:
    df1 = pd.read_html(urlx, attrs={'id':'abc'})[0]
    dfs['URL'] = urlx
    df = df.append(df1, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

Here's off your code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0)'}

#years_url = ['https://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=bbr&url=%2Fplayers%2Fi%2Fiversal01.html&div=div_playoffs_per_game']
years_url = ['https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/o/odomla01.html','https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/r/russebi01.html']

df = pd.DataFrame() #< Initialize empty dataframe before loop
for year_url in years_url:
    res = requests.get(year_url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', id='per_game')

    df1 = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    df1['player'] = year_url  #<---- HERE WAS YOUR ERROR
    df1['Name'] = soup.find('h1',{'itemprop':'name'}).text #<-- I added this

    df = df.append(df1, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

df.to_csv('123.csv', index=False) #<--- Took this out of the for loop
```

OR

```
import pandas as pd

#years_url = ['https://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=bbr&url=%2Fplayers%2Fi%2Fiversal01.html&div=div_playoffs_per_game']
years_url = ['https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/o/odomla01.html','https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/r/russebi01.html']

df = pd.DataFrame() #< Took this out of the for loop
for year_url in years_url:
    df1 = pd.read_html(year_url, attrs={'id':'per_game'})[0]
    df1['player'] = year_url
    df = df.append(df1, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

df.to_csv('123.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Unfortunately, I get the error:
` in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0`

Comment: can you give the list of urls?

Comment: you the real MVP!

Thanks, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

is this what you looking for? :

```
import pandas as pd 
df1=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'id':[1,3,4],
        'name':[1,5,7],
        'dob':[100,105,110]
                 })

df2=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'id':[6,4,4],
        'name':[1,4,4],
        'dob':[10,10,12],
        'nationality':['usa','ger','swe'],
        'years':[11,22,33] })

print(df1)
   dob  id  name
0  100   1     1
1  105   3     5
2  110   4     7

print(df2)
   dob  id  name nationality  years
0   10   6     1         usa     11
1   10   4     4         ger     22
2   12   4     4         swe     33

df_list=[df1,df2]
df=pd.concat(df_list,sort=False)

print(df)

   dob  id  name nationality  years
0  100   1     1         NaN    NaN
1  105   3     5         NaN    NaN
2  110   4     7         NaN    NaN
0   10   6     1         usa   11.0
1   10   4     4         ger   22.0
2   12   4     4         swe   33.0
```